# Increase time limit in HPC

Tags: python, time, iteration, limit, hpc

I am using the Massachusetts HPC to run an iterative process which performs (by submitting one job at a time) 4 simulations at each round. My code, which is the iterative process, is submitted as job as well. The maximum time is 12 hours and the RAM 48G. So, after 12 hours, the job is canceled. This is useless for me, since each simulation last about 8 hrs and they cannot run in parallel. 
Do you have any idea how can I make this work? Would it be requesting for more nodes?
Thanks! 
PS. I work in python if this is needed to provide an answer

Comment: Hi Katerina, Which Massachusetts cluster do you use? Most of them I know about have queues that can run longer than 12 hours. Also what scheduler is used on your cluster (SLURM, SGE)? If you do not know what scheduler, you can specify which command you use to submit a job on your cluster. To answer your main question, you can look into job dependency option. If you provide the info about the scheduler on your cluster I can further help you.

Comment: I was using the Green HPPC. Finally I stopped working there as it was not feasible to get more time per job. @katia